# Github self-hosted runner complains of python version -

Tags: python, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to set a GitHub self-hosted runner for my project and I keep getting the following error:

> Run actions/setup-python@v3
> Version 3.9 was not found in the local cache
> Error: Version 3.9 with arch x64 not found
> The list of all available versions can be found here: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/actions/python-versions/main/versions-manifest.json`

I have to install pytorch, and so I could not use the runners provided by GitHub. The python version of the machine where the runner is installed is `Python 3.9.13`, and the operational system is `AlmaLinux release 9.3 (Shamrock Pampas Cat)`.

I am also linking the .yaml file responsible for the workflow:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:

    # Due to cuda constraings, I needed to set up a self-hosted runner!
    #runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.9
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.9"
        cache: "pip"
      env:
        AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY: /opt/hostedtoolcache
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest

        # Do I need to create the full enviroment =p
        #conda env create -f environment.yml
        #conda activate flow_corrections

        if [ -f requirements.yml ]; then pip install -r requirements.yml; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest *.py
```

I know that the python version written here is 3.9, but I also tested writing 3.9.13 and I got the same error!

I am also making available the requirements.yml for the condo environment:

```
name: flow_corrections
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=2_kmp_llvm
  - _py-xgboost-mutex=2.0=gpu_0
  - alsa-lib=1.2.8=h166bdaf_0
  - attr=2.5.1=h166bdaf_1
  - boost-histogram=1.4.0=py310hd41b1e2_1
  - brotli=1.1.0=hd590300_1
  - brotli-bin=1.1.0=hd590300_1
  - bzip2=1.0.8=hd590300_5
  - ca-certificates=2023.11.17=hbcca054_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=hbbf8b49_1016
  - certifi=2023.11.17=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=8.1.7=unix_pyh707e725_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - contourpy=1.2.0=py310hd41b1e2_0
  - cramjam=2.7.0=py310hcb5633a_1
  - cuda-cudart=12.0.107=hd3aeb46_7
  - cuda-cudart_linux-64=12.0.107=h59595ed_7
  - cuda-nvrtc=12.0.76=hd3aeb46_2
  - cuda-nvtx=12.0.76=h59595ed_1
  - cuda-version=12.0=hffde075_2
  - cudnn=8.8.0.121=h264754d_4
  - cycler=0.12.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dbus=1.13.6=h5008d03_3
  - exceptiongroup=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - expat=2.5.0=hcb278e6_1
  - fastparquet=2023.10.1=py310h1f7b6fc_0
  - filelock=3.13.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono=2.37=hab24e00_0
  - font-ttf-inconsolata=3.000=h77eed37_0
  - font-ttf-source-code-pro=2.038=h77eed37_0
  - font-ttf-ubuntu=0.83=h77eed37_1
  - fontconfig=2.14.2=h14ed4e7_0
  - fonts-conda-ecosystem=1=0
  - fonts-conda-forge=1=0
  - fonttools=4.46.0=py310h2372a71_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=h267a509_2
  - fsspec=2023.12.1=pyhca7485f_0
  - gettext=0.21.1=h27087fc_0
  - glib=2.78.3=hfc55251_0
  - glib-tools=2.78.3=hfc55251_0
  - gmp=6.3.0=h59595ed_0
  - gmpy2=2.1.2=py310h3ec546c_1
  - graphite2=1.3.13=h58526e2_1001
  - gst-plugins-base=1.22.3=h938bd60_1
  - gstreamer=1.22.3=h977cf35_1
  - harfbuzz=7.3.0=hdb3a94d_0
  - hep_ml=0.7.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - hist=2.7.2=ha770c72_1
  - hist-base=2.7.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - histoprint=2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - icu=72.1=hcb278e6_0
  - iminuit=2.24.0=py310hc6cd4ac_0
  - iniconfig=2.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jinja2=3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - joblib=1.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - keyutils=1.6.1=h166bdaf_0
  - kiwisolver=1.4.5=py310hd41b1e2_1
  - krb5=1.20.1=h81ceb04_0
  - lame=3.100=h166bdaf_1003
  - lcms2=2.15=h7f713cb_2
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.40=h41732ed_0
  - lerc=4.0.0=h27087fc_0
  - libabseil=20230802.1=cxx17_h59595ed_0
  - libblas=3.9.0=20_linux64_openblas
  - libbrotlicommon=1.1.0=hd590300_1
  - libbrotlidec=1.1.0=hd590300_1
  - libbrotlienc=1.1.0=hd590300_1
  - libcap=2.69=h0f662aa_0
  - libcblas=3.9.0=20_linux64_openblas
  - libclang=16.0.6=default_hb11cfb5_3
  - libclang13=16.0.6=default_ha2b6cf4_3
  - libcublas=12.0.1.189=hd3aeb46_3
  - libcufft=11.0.0.21=hd3aeb46_2
  - libcups=2.3.3=h36d4200_3
  - libcurand=10.3.1.50=hd3aeb46_1
  - libcusolver=11.4.2.57=hd3aeb46_2
  - libcusparse=12.0.0.76=hd3aeb46_2
  - libdeflate=1.19=hd590300_0
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=he28a2e2_2
  - libevent=2.1.12=hf998b51_1
  - libexpat=2.5.0=hcb278e6_1
  - libffi=3.4.2=h7f98852_5
  - libflac=1.4.3=h59595ed_0
  - libgcc-ng=13.2.0=h807b86a_3
  - libgcrypt=1.10.3=hd590300_0
  - libgfortran-ng=13.2.0=h69a702a_3
  - libgfortran5=13.2.0=ha4646dd_3
  - libglib=2.78.3=h783c2da_0
  - libgpg-error=1.47=h71f35ed_0
  - libhwloc=2.9.3=default_h554bfaf_1009
  - libiconv=1.17=h166bdaf_0
  - libjpeg-turbo=2.1.5.1=hd590300_1
  - liblapack=3.9.0=20_linux64_openblas
  - libllvm16=16.0.6=h5cf9203_2
  - libmagma=2.7.2=h173bb3b_1
  - libmagma_sparse=2.7.2=h173bb3b_1
  - libnsl=2.0.1=hd590300_0
  - libnvjitlink=12.0.76=hd3aeb46_2
  - libogg=1.3.4=h7f98852_1
  - libopenblas=0.3.25=pthreads_h413a1c8_0
  - libopus=1.3.1=h7f98852_1
  - libpng=1.6.39=h753d276_0
  - libpq=15.3=hbcd7760_1
  - libprotobuf=4.24.4=hf27288f_0
  - libsndfile=1.2.2=hc60ed4a_1
  - libsqlite=3.44.2=h2797004_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=13.2.0=h7e041cc_3
  - libsystemd0=255=h3516f8a_0
  - libtiff=4.6.0=h29866fb_1
  - libuuid=2.38.1=h0b41bf4_0
  - libuv=1.46.0=hd590300_0
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=h9c3ff4c_0
  - libwebp-base=1.3.2=hd590300_0
  - libxcb=1.15=h0b41bf4_0
  - libxgboost=1.7.6=cuda120_h75debf4_6
  - libxkbcommon=1.6.0=h5d7e998_0
  - libxml2=2.11.5=h0d562d8_0
  - libzlib=1.2.13=hd590300_5
  - llvm-openmp=17.0.6=h4dfa4b3_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=hcb278e6_0
  - magma=2.7.2=h51420fd_1
  - markupsafe=2.1.3=py310h2372a71_1
  - matplotlib=3.8.2=py310hff52083_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.8.2=py310h62c0568_0
  - mkl=2022.2.1=h84fe81f_16997
  - mpc=1.3.1=hfe3b2da_0
  - mpfr=4.2.1=h9458935_0
  - mpg123=1.32.3=h59595ed_0
  - mplhep=0.3.31=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mplhep_data=0.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mpmath=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - munkres=1.1.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - mysql-common=8.0.33=hf1915f5_6
  - mysql-libs=8.0.33=hca2cd23_6
  - nccl=2.19.4.1=h3a97aeb_0
  - ncurses=6.4=h59595ed_2
  - networkx=3.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nspr=4.35=h27087fc_0
  - nss=3.95=h1d7d5a4_0
  - numpy=1.26.2=py310hb13e2d6_0
  - openjpeg=2.5.0=h488ebb8_3
  - openssl=3.1.4=hd590300_0
  - packaging=23.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pandas=2.1.3=py310hcc13569_0
  - pcre2=10.42=hcad00b1_0
  - pillow=10.0.1=py310h29da1c1_1
  - pip=23.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pixman=0.42.2=h59595ed_0
  - pluggy=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ply=3.11=py_1
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=h36c2ea0_1001
  - pulseaudio-client=16.1=hb77b528_5
  - py-xgboost=1.7.6=cuda120_py310h6bc6e9e_6
  - pyparsing=3.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyqt=5.15.9=py310h04931ad_5
  - pyqt5-sip=12.12.2=py310hc6cd4ac_5
  - pytest=7.4.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python=3.10.13=hd12c33a_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python_abi=3.10=4_cp310
  - pytorch=2.1.0=cuda120py310ha3a684c_301
  - pytz=2023.3.post1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyyaml=6.0.1=py310h5eee18b_0
  - qt-main=5.15.8=h01ceb2d_12
  - readline=8.2=h8228510_1
  - scikit-learn=1.3.2=py310h1fdf081_2
  - scipy=1.11.4=py310hb13e2d6_0
  - setuptools=68.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sip=6.7.12=py310hc6cd4ac_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - sleef=3.5.1=h9b69904_2
  - sympy=1.12=pypyh9d50eac_103
  - tbb=2021.11.0=h00ab1b0_0
  - threadpoolctl=3.2.0=pyha21a80b_0
  - tk=8.6.13=noxft_h4845f30_101
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tornado=6.3.3=py310h2372a71_1
  - typing-extensions=4.8.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.8.0=pyha770c72_0
  - tzdata=2023c=h71feb2d_0
  - uhi=0.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - unicodedata2=15.1.0=py310h2372a71_0
  - wheel=0.42.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xcb-util=0.4.0=hd590300_1
  - xcb-util-image=0.4.0=h8ee46fc_1
  - xcb-util-keysyms=0.4.0=h8ee46fc_1
  - xcb-util-renderutil=0.3.9=hd590300_1
  - xcb-util-wm=0.4.1=h8ee46fc_1
  - xgboost=1.7.6=cuda120_py310h6bc6e9e_6
  - xkeyboard-config=2.40=hd590300_0
  - xorg-kbproto=1.0.7=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-libice=1.1.1=hd590300_0
  - xorg-libsm=1.2.4=h7391055_0
  - xorg-libx11=1.8.7=h8ee46fc_0
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.11=hd590300_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxext=1.3.4=h0b41bf4_2
  - xorg-libxrender=0.9.11=hd590300_0
  - xorg-renderproto=0.11.1=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-xextproto=7.3.0=h0b41bf4_1003
  - xorg-xf86vidmodeproto=2.3.1=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-xproto=7.0.31=h7f98852_1007
  - xz=5.2.6=h166bdaf_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h7f98852_2
  - zlib=1.2.13=hd590300_5
  - zstd=1.5.5=hfc55251_0
  - pip:
    - zuko==1.0.1
prefix: /home/home1/institut_3a/daumann/.conda/envs/flow_corrections
```

I cannot really see what is wrong, and I don't have much experience with this, so I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#using-setup-python-with-a-self-hosted-runner), the `setup-python` action requires that you use a specific version of Ubuntu or Windows (same as the GitHub Actions environments) for the Action to work properly. As noted (emphasis added):

> Python distributions are only available for the same [environments](https://github.com/actions/runner-images#available-images) that GitHub Actions hosted environments are available for. **If you are using an unsupported version of Ubuntu such as `19.04` or another Linux distribution such as Fedora, `setup-python` may not work**.

Since you noted you are using AlmaLinux (which is not an Ubuntu or even Debian-based OS), that would likely be the reason why you are experiencing this issue.

Comment: Hi @sytech thanks for your answer! That means I cannot use a GitHub self-hosted runner in that machine? There is no way around this?

Comment: @MatthewD you can use a supported platform on your self-hosted runner, such as Ubuntu or Windows. Short of that, it would seem you cannot use this Action.

Comment: @systech I see, well looks like I have to find another machine then. Thanks for the answer and clarifications!